# Postgresql server refuses connection despite authorizing it

Tags: java, postgresql, database-connection

I'm connecting to a Postgresql server (version 8.4) with a Spring application.

My connection parameters are:

```
<Environment name="/db/driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
<Environment name="/db/jdbc_url" value="jdbc:postgresql://test.server.com:5432/dev_database" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
<Environment name="/db/user" value="user" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
<Environment name="/db/password" value="password" type="java.lang.String" override="false" />
```

These parameters are correct (I can connect using, for example, PgAdminn), but I'm still receiving a `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.` error.

When checking database logs, it looks like it successfully authorizes the connection attempts:

```
LOG:  00000: connection authorized: user=user database=dev_database
LOCATION:  BackendInitialize, postmaster.c:3352
LOG:  00000: connection authorized: user=user database=dev_database
LOCATION:  BackendInitialize, postmaster.c:3352
LOG:  00000: connection authorized: user=user database=dev_database
LOCATION:  BackendInitialize, postmaster.c:3352
LOG:  00000: connection received: host=lyys.server.com port=51279
LOCATION:  BackendInitialize, postmaster.c:3274
LOG:  00000: connection received: host=lyys.server.com port=51280
LOCATION:  BackendInitialize, postmaster.c:3274
LOG:  00000: connection authorized: user=user database=dev_database
LOCATION:  BackendInitialize, postmaster.c:3352
LOG:  00000: connection authorized: user=user database=dev_database
LOCATION:  BackendInitialize, postmaster.c:3352
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I just tunneled the 5432 port to my computer and changed `test.server.com` to `localhost`. Works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are almost always firewall issues or some other program or piece of hardware in between these systems.  You can either disable the firewall, or preferably, tunnel through SSH or the like, as you did.  Tunnelling, because it provides less exposure to problems security-wise, is definitely preferable.  If that fails, then you can take a look at troubleshooting this as a network issue.